# How to convert string to Date in apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, date

What is wrong with this format while am upserting the date in an object?

```
    Route__c r =new Route_c();
    r.Plan_Date__c = date.parse(strDate);
    upsert r;
```

In the debug log, I get the error as **|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Invalid date: Test123**

Here Test123 is the different text to be inserted which accepts as Date and throws an error.

Comment: so does it work fine if you give a valid date like '01/14/2016'?

Comment: you'll be much happier if all incoming dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format to avoid locale-specific issues

Comment: Why do you think 'Test123' is a valid date in any locale?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This error is coming as system is not able to understand `Test123` while parsing into date.

The format of the String depends on the local date format, like `mm/dd/yyyy`. If the parameter is not of this format, `date.parse` will throw an error.

E.g.:

```java
r.Plan_Date__c = date.parse('12/27/2015');
```

You can also use `date.valueOf(strDate)` to parse string of format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in the local time zone.

Please [read about more date properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse).

Answer (score 19):

In case this is helpful to anyone, here is the Apex code to convert a string containing a date into an instance of the standard Date class (without going through the Datetime class or doing anything else funny). Note: It's important that the string be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
Date x = Date.valueOf('2015-12-31');
```

You can read more about the Date class here: [Date Class | Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm).