# Apex Test - either Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Date or Invalid Date

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

I am trying to test code that takes a URL string and maps it into fields and values. I am having trouble with the date and date/time fields. In the following code I get the error message "Invalid date: 4/18/2023". If I take out the IsRunningTest section I get the error message "Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Date". I have also tried

- putting the date directly into the test class '04/18/2023' replacing .put(Delivery_Date__c, dateToday);
- putting the date directly in the class in the IsRunningTest section value = Date.valueOf('04/18/2023');

**Test Class**

```
static testMethod void customObject() {
    String dateToday = Date.today().format();
    String dateTimeNow = DateTime.now().format();
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.RedirectWithVariables);
    RedirectWithVariablesController controller = new RedirectWithVariablesController();
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('object', 'Kimble_Scheduling_Request__c');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('allowRTS','true');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Name','Test');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Delivery_Date__c',dateToday);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Completion_Date__c',dateTimeNow);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Account_Name__c','0018H00000I00MQQAZ');
    
    PageReference pageRef = controller.redirectUser();
}
```

**StaticFunction Class**

```
for (SObjectField field : oGeneric.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
            
            //Get the field description object
            DescribeFieldResult f = field.getDescribe();
            
            String label = f.getLabel();        //Get label name
            String apiName = f.getName();       //Get API name

    Object value = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(apiName);
                if (test.isRunningTest()){
                    if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Date) {
                            value = Date.valueOf(value);
                        } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Datetime) {
                            value = DateTime.valueOf(value);
                        } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Boolean) {
                            if (value != null){
                            value = Boolean.valueOf(value);
                        }
                        } else {
                            value = String.valueOf(value);
                        }
                }
                
                        
                //If we have a value
                if (value != null) {
                    system.debug('value is ' +value);
                    //If there is a label              
                    if (mLabelToID.containsKey(label)) {
    
                        // Format the given value as required
                        String valueAsString;
                        system.debug('f.getType is ' +f.getType());
                        if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Date) {
                            valueAsString = ((Date) value).format();
                        } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Datetime) {
                            valueAsString = ((Datetime) value).format();
                        } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Boolean) {
                            valueAsString = ((Boolean) value) ? '1' : '0';
                        } else {
                            valueAsString = String.valueOf(value);
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the Date format in 'yyyy-MM-dd' before calling Date.valueOf() ? [Check this post too](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105377/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-apex)

Comment: Subrat, changing the code in the IsRunningTest to value = date.parse('04/18/2023') worked. I thought I had tried it but evidently not. Thanks!