# Date conversion from string dd-mmm-yy

Tags: integration, date, formatting, conversion

I am getting date as a string '03-Sep-24' from an external system. What is the easiest way to parse it and save it in a date field?

Comment: I think this question will help you.. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105377/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-apex

Comment: Nope i have month here as text intead of a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was to manually create a map of month and their number values and create a  string which apex can parse. Any better answer is appreciated.

```
 Public static Date convertStringToDate(String value){
    Map<String,String> monthNumberConversionMap=new Map<String,String>{'JAN'=>'1','FEB'=>'2','MAR'=>'3','APR'=>'4','MAY'=>'5','JUN'=>'6','JUL'=>'7','AUG'=>'8','SEP'=>'9','OCT'=>'10','NOV'=>'11','DEC'=>'12'};
                Date valueToReturn=null;
    if(!String.IsBlanK(value)){
        try{
            String[] splitstr=value.split('-');
            String dd=splitstr[0];
            String mmm=splitstr[1];
            String yy=splitstr[2];
            valueToReturn=Date.valueOf('20'+yy+'-'+monthNumberConversionMap.get(mmm.toUpperCase())+'-'+dd);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception '+e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return valueToReturn;
}
```